# what _ means in expression: reprColor = [_("White"), _("Black")] and why it fails

Tags: python

There is a file const.py with lines like this:

```
 reprColor = [ _("White"), _("Black")]
```

I got an error on this line:

```
NameError: name '_' is not defined<br>
```

What is the problem?
Environment: Python 2.7 / Windows XP

I have read that underscore is used as convention for private variables.

Comment: Underscore by itself is used by some folks as a convention for a variable whose value you want to discard, but not in this case. See answers below.

Answer (score 2):

A single underscore is used as convention for one of the translation functions in [`gettext`](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html). Either bind it yourself, or call one of the `install()` functions or methods.

Answer (score 0):

[A _() call usually means GNU gettext is in use](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#gettext.gettext).  It's for internationalization of strings.

Comment: Strictly speaking, Python's `gettext` is a reimplementation and does not in fact use GNU gettext.

Comment: (Assuming you happen to be using today's most popular python implementation, true enough.)  And yet the call itself is still using the GNU gettext API.